# stringstream.rdbuf causing cout to fail

Tags: c++

I was surprised to see my program suddenly go quiet when I added a cout at some point, so I isolated the responsible code:

```
std::stringstream data;
data<<"Hello World\n";
std:std::fstream file{"hello.txt", std::fstream::out};
file<<data.rdbuf();
std::cout<<"now rdbuf..."<<std::endl;
std::cout<<data.rdbuf()<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"rdbuf done."<< std::endl;
```

The program quietly exits without the final cout. What is going on? If I change the last `.rdbuf()` to `.str()` instead then it completes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During the call to `std::cout<<data.rdbuf()`, `std::cout` is unable to read any characters from `data`'s `filebuf` because the read position is already at the end of the file after the previous output; [accordingly](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt), this sets `failbit` on `std::cout`, and until this state is cleared any further output will fail too (i.e. your final line is essentially ignored).

`std::cout<<data.str()<<std::endl;` will not cause `cout` to enter a failed state because `data.str()` returns a copy of the underlying string regardless of where the read position is (for mixed-mode stringstreams anyway).

Comment: Ok so it doesn't actually abort then, I updated my question to be smarter.

Comment: Alternatively, you can `if ( data.rdbuf()->in_avail() ) std::cout << data.rdbuf();` , so you save one temporary std::string. Not sure anyone should care about that though. And thanks for both question and answer! Saved my day.